# How to group data by day range in PGSQL?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am wanting to do the following

```
SELECT
  MIN(readings.value) as min,
  AVG(readings.value) as ave,
  MAX(readings.value) as max,
  SUM(readings.value) as total,
  to_char(readings.time, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as day
FROM readings
WHERE 
  AND readings.time >= $1
  AND readings.time < $2
GROUP BY day
ORDER BY day
```

this query works fine, but to make it more interesting, the `day` needs to be `9am yesterday to 8:59:59am today`, instead of being `midnight to midnight` the same day.

The data needs to span over a week, and then be grouped by day.
So
the data returned should be something like

| min | ave | max | total | day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.4 | 4 | 10 | 25 | 2022-03-21 |
| 0.4 | 4 | 10 | 26 | 2022-03-22 |
| 0.4 | 4 | 10 | 23 | 2022-03-23 |
| 0.4 | 4 | 10 | 28 | 2022-03-24 |
| 0.4 | 4 | 10 | 5 | 2022-03-25 |
| 0.4 | 4 | 10 | 19 | 2022-03-26 |
| 0.4 | 4 | 10 | 25 | 2022-03-27 |

`2022-03-21` = `2022-03-20 09:00:00 - 2022-03-21 08:59:59`
`2022-03-22` = `2022-03-21 09:00:00 - 2022-03-22 08:59:59`
`2022-03-23` = `2022-03-22 09:00:00 - 2022-03-23 08:59:59`
`2022-03-24` = `2022-03-23 09:00:00 - 2022-03-24 08:59:59`
`2022-03-25` = `2022-03-24 09:00:00 - 2022-03-25 08:59:59`
`2022-03-26` = `2022-03-25 09:00:00 - 2022-03-26 08:59:59`
`2022-03-27` = `2022-03-26 09:00:00 - 2022-03-27 08:59:59`

Pgsql version is 9.6
The time field is `timestamp`.
Timezone is in UTC for all readings

Is this possible with postgres?

Comment: Easily possible. But disclose your table definition and Postgres version first. `timestamp` or `timestamptz`? Does the time zone matter? How?

Comment: What data type is `day`?  Over how many 'days'? Add answers as update to your question.

Comment: So just shift the `time` by three hours before passing it to `to_char`?

Comment: I have updated the question based on the questions above

Answer (score 0):

That should be as simple as

```
SELECT ...,
  to_char(
     (readings.time + INTERVAL '9 hours')::date,
     'YYYY-MM-DD'
  ) as day
FROM readings
WHERE ...
GROUP BY (readings.time + INTERVAL '9 hours')::date
ORDER BY day;
```

You cannot use an alias in the `GROUP BY` clause.